# Logging object but not able to log the object keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have saved an object in Redis in this format

```
 let redisObject = {
  sessionID: this.data.sessionID,
  forWardTime: new Date(),
 };
```

I am calling the object and the data is being retrieved successfully

```
  let redisData = await this.getDataFromRedis ....
```

And the weird part I am being able to log the Redis data example

```
console.log("redisData =>",redisData)
```

it is returing

```
redisData => {"sessionID":"OyMUuUgeimTeU3OfNWyDtgkGeHsniF","forWardTime":"2022-03-22T19:16:05.507Z"}
```

But

```
console.log(redisData.sessionID)
```

And

```
console.log(redisData.forWardTime)
```

are both returning undefined? What's the problem and what am I missing

Comment: Exactly how are those `console.log()` calls arranged in your code? Are they really one after another in the same function?

Comment: They are below the  redisData of course

Comment: It's because you are trying to call an asynchronous object property synchronously and it's giving undefined

Comment: How should i call it then ?

Comment: I already assigned redisData  in asynchronous  way

Comment: @SeanLawton They use `await`, so it shouldn't log asynchronously.

Comment: Why its logging redisData then ?

Comment: This happens in a browser because the log has a live reference to the object. I don't think the same thing happens in node.js.

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log("redisData =>",JSON.stringify(redisData))`?

Comment: You didn't really answer my question: are all those `console.log()` statements **in the same function**?

Comment: Yes they are in the same function

Comment: @Barmar the same result is being returned

Comment: So `console.log("redisData =>", redisData); console.log(redisData.sessionId);`, one statement right after another.

Comment: @Pointy yes ...

Comment: could you please post the entire code?

Comment: What does `typeof redisData` return? I suspect it's a JSON string, you need to parse it with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Barmar it is already parsed in the getDataFromRedis method.

Comment: Humor me and add `console.log(typeof redisData);`

Comment: @Barmar Its a string :O

Comment: It's being parsed in the getDataFromRedis method but still returining string thats wierd @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Your `getDataFromRedis()` function isn't parsing the data, so you're logging the JSON string, not an object.

Change to:

```
let redisData = JSON.parse(await this.getDataFromRedis(...));
```